# How to disassemble win32 function RegSetValueExW?

Tags: ida, windows, winapi, api-reversing

I have opened up `advapi32.dll` in IDA and found out that `RegSetValueExW` is just a jump to `RegSetValueExW_0`. And `RegSetValueExW_0` seems to be an extern.

How do I actually disassemble `RegSetValueExW_0`?

[image: ida1]

[image: ida2]

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. I think you have a few misconceptions there. Please read up [here](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/windows_7_kernel_architecture_changes.html) and [here](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/apisetschema/index.htm) ...

Comment: Try looking in api-ms-win-core-registry-l1-1-0.dll (or the specific version that your advapi32.dll is importing from).

Comment: @joshpoley why would you want to do _that_? After all these API set DLLs only contain "empty" stubs ... the real code for said function - as for most of the "meat" of the old Win32 API - moved to `kernelbase.dll` ... see the links I posted before.